# intl-tel-input in angular js is not validating when I enter a single digit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I am using intl-tel-input in one of my forms and when I enter a two digit or three digit number and try to save it a validation error is thrown saying that the number entered is invalid. But when I enter a single digit number it does not throw any validation error and it goes through. While debugging I found that when a single digit is entered the number retrieved is empty.The following is the code I am using:

HTML:

```
<intl-tel-input set-fn="setDirectiveFn(theDirFn)" 
                ng-class="form-control"
                phone-number="admin.PhoneNumber" >
</intl-tel-input>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('TestApp').directive('intlTelInput', ['$log', function ($log) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      setFn: '&',
      phoneNumber: '=',
      ngClass: '@'
    },
    template: '<input type="tel" maxlength="25"/>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var utilsScript = "Scripts/intl-tel-input-master/lib/libphonenumber/build/utils.js";
            var el = element.find('input');
            el.intlTelInput({
              //allowExtensions: true,
              autoFormat: true,
              autoHideDialCode: true,
              autoPlaceholder: true,
              defaultCountry: 'us',
              nationalMode: true,
              numberType: 'FIXED_LINE_OR_MOBILE',
              preferredCountries: ['us', 'gb'],
              utilsScript: utilsScript
            });

            angular.element.getScript(utilsScript, function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
              // $log.debug(data); // Data returned
              // $log.debug(textStatus); // Success
              // $log.debug(jqxhr.status); // 200
              // $log.debug("Load was performed.");
            });

            //$log.debug(JSON.stringify(attrs.ngClass, 0,3));
            angular.element(el).addClass(scope.ngClass);

            function getNumber(cb) {
              var phoneNumber = el.intlTelInput("getNumber");
              var isValid = el.intlTelInput("isValidNumber");
              var validationError = el.intlTelInput("getValidationError");
              //$log.debug('validation error',validationError);
              var errorType = intlTelInputUtils.validationError;
              var errorMessage = "Invalid phone number";
              // if(validationError == intlTelInputUtils.validationError.TOO_SHORT)
              //     errorMessage = "phone number is too short";
              // else if(validationError == intlTelInputUtils.validationError.TOO_LONG)
              //     errorMessage = "phone number is too long";
              // else if(validationError == intlTelInputUtils.validationError.NOT_A_NUMBER)
              //     errorMessage = "phone number is not a number";
              cb(isValid ? null : errorMessage, phoneNumber);
            }

            scope.setFn({theDirFn: getNumber});

            scope.$watch('phoneNumber', function(nv, ov){
              $log.debug('phoneNumber', nv, ov);
              if (nv) {
                //$log.debug('setNumber', nv);
                el.intlTelInput("setNumber", nv);
              }
            });

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
              el.intlTelInput("destroy");
            });
    }
  };
}]);
```

Could you let me know what I am missing here. When I enter a single digit it should still throw an error saying "Invalid phone number".

Comment: Does it only happen if your single digit is 1?  Just wondering if the utils are parsing out the 1 which would be the default locale (US) prefix for a phone # and then seeing it empty, returning blank.

Comment: No.It also happens when I use any other digit.

Comment: Have you tried raising an issue with the intl-tel-input library on github? I noticed the same problem when I enter just the international dialling code...

Comment: No. I added a custom javascript validation in my case.